# How to Pass(convert) Json format of data as Graphql Query and filter out data flask graphene

Tags: flask, graphene-python

{"user_id":180,"user_gender":"Female","pref_min_age":null,"pref_min_height":null,"pref_max_age":null,"pref_max_height":null,"pref_marital_status":"Married","pref_religion":null,"pref_caste":null,"pref_sub_caste":null,"pref_gotra":null, "pref_mother_tongue":"Hindi","pref_appearance":"Fair","pref_body_type":"slim","pref_eye_color":null,"pref_hair_color":null,"pref_eye_sight":null,"pref_disability":null,"pref_eating_habits":null,"pref_religious_beliefs":null,"pref_astrological_status":null,"pref_highest_edu":null,"pref_residential_status":null,"pref_occupation":null,"pref_annual_income":null,"pref_family_values":null}

I want to generte graphql query by using above json data and filterout from database (e.PRefrence.usergener==data['user_gender'] ).

How Can I solve this in python flask using graphene?